# Uncorrectly modeling data from Json API response

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to fetch data from my API in Flutter. I am able to fetch data from the rest of the fields but not for "Behavior" field.

Here's my json:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "625f2900fe6aeb351381c3f5"
    }, 
    "breed": "Africanis", 
    "origin": "Southern Africa", 
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africanis", 
    "img": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Africanis_%281%29.jpg/220px-Africanis_%281%29.jpg", 
    "WikiDescr": [
      {
        "contenido": "some content"
      }
    ], 
    "Behavior": [
      {
        "good_with_children": 3, 
        "good_with_other_dogs": 1, 
        "shedding": 3, 
        "grooming": 3, 
        "drooling": 1, 
        "coat_length": 1, 
        "good_with_strangers": 2, 
        "playfulness": 3, 
        "protectiveness": 5, 
        "trainability": 3, 
        "energy": 4, 
        "barking": 2, 
        "min_life_expectancy": 10, 
        "max_life_expectancy": 14, 
        "max_height_male": 28, 
        "max_height_female": 28, 
        "max_weight_male": 130, 
        "max_weight_female": 100, 
        "min_height_male": 26, 
        "min_height_female": 26, 
        "min_weight_male": 100, 
        "min_weight_female": 70
      }
    ], 
    "url_alternative": []
  }
]
```

And here's my dart model generated from https://app.quicktype.io/ :

```
class DogClass {
  Id? _iId;
  String? _breed;
  String? _origin;
  String? _url;
  String? _img;
  List<WikiDescr>? _wikiDescr;
  List<Behavior>? _behavior;
  List<dynamic>? _urlAlternative;

  DogClass({
    Id? iId,
    String? breed,
    String? origin,
    String? url,
    String? img,
    List<WikiDescr>? wikiDescr,
    List<Behavior>? behavior,
    List<dynamic>? urlAlternative
  }) {
    if (iId != null) {
      this._iId = iId;
    }
    if (breed != null) {
      this._breed = breed;
    }
    if (origin != null) {
      this._origin = origin;
    }
    if (url != null) {
      this._url = url;
    }
    if (img != null) {
      this._img = img;
    }
    if (img != null) {
      this._img = img;
    }
    if (wikiDescr != null) {
      this._wikiDescr = wikiDescr;
    }
    if (behavior != null) {
      this._behavior = behavior;
    }
    if (urlAlternative != null) {
      this._urlAlternative = urlAlternative;
    }
  }

  Id? get iId => _iId;
  set iId(Id? iId) => _iId = iId;
  String? get breed => _breed;
  set breed(String? breed) => _breed = breed;
  String? get origin => _origin;
  set origin(String? origin) => _origin = origin;
  String? get url => _url;
  set url(String? url) => _url = url;
  String? get img => _img;
  set img(String? img) => _img = img;
  List<WikiDescr>? get wikiDescr => _wikiDescr;
  set wikiDescr(List<WikiDescr>? wikiDescr) => _wikiDescr = wikiDescr;

  List<Behavior>? get behavior => _behavior;
  set behavior(List<Behavior>? behavior) => _behavior = behavior;
  
  List<dynamic>? get urlAlternative => _urlAlternative;
  set urlAlternative(List<dynamic>? urlAlternative) => _urlAlternative = urlAlternative;

  factory DogClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DogClass(
      iId: json['_id'] == null
          ? null
          : Id.fromJson(json['_id'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      breed: json['breed'] as String?,
      origin: json['origin'] as String?,
      url: json['url'] as String?,
      img: json['img'] as String?,
      wikiDescr: List<WikiDescr>.from(
          json["WikiDescr"].map((x) => WikiDescr.fromJson(x))),
      behavior: List<Behavior>.from(json["Behavior"].map((x) => Behavior.fromJson(x))),
      urlAlternative: List<UrlAlternative>.from(json["url_alternative"].map((x) => UrlAlternative.fromJson(x)))
    );
  }
}

class Id {
  String? _oid;

  Id({String? oid}) {
    if (oid != null) {
      this._oid = oid;
    }
  }

  String? get oid => _oid;
  set oid(String? oid) => _oid = oid;

  Id.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _oid = json['$oid'];
  }
}

class WikiDescr {
  WikiDescr({
    required this.contenido,
  });

  String contenido;

  factory WikiDescr.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      WikiDescr.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory WikiDescr.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => WikiDescr(
        contenido: json["contenido"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "contenido": contenido,
      };
}

class Behavior {
  int? _goodWithChildren;
  int? _goodWithOtherDogs;
  int? _shedding;
  int? _grooming;
  int? _drooling;
  int? _coatLength;
  int? _goodWithStrangers;
  int? _playfulness;
  int? _protectiveness;
  int? _trainability;
  int? _energy;
  int? _barking;
  int? _minLifeExpectancy;
  int? _maxLifeExpectancy;
  int? _maxHeightMale;
  int? _maxHeightFemale;
  int? _maxWeightMale;
  int? _maxWeightFemale;
  int? _minHeightMale;
  int? _minHeightFemale;
  int? _minWeightMale;
  int? _minWeightFemale;

  Behavior(
      {int? goodWithChildren,
      int? goodWithOtherDogs,
      int? shedding,
      int? grooming,
      int? drooling,
      int? coatLength,
      int? goodWithStrangers,
      int? playfulness,
      int? protectiveness,
      int? trainability,
      int? energy,
      int? barking,
      int? minLifeExpectancy,
      int? maxLifeExpectancy,
      int? maxHeightMale,
      int? maxHeightFemale,
      int? maxWeightMale,
      int? maxWeightFemale,
      int? minHeightMale,
      int? minHeightFemale,
      int? minWeightMale,
      int? minWeightFemale}) {
    if (goodWithChildren != null) {
      this._goodWithChildren = goodWithChildren;
    }
    if (goodWithOtherDogs != null) {
      this._goodWithOtherDogs = goodWithOtherDogs;
    }
    if (shedding != null) {
      this._shedding = shedding;
    }
    if (grooming != null) {
      this._grooming = grooming;
    }
    if (drooling != null) {
      this._drooling = drooling;
    }
    if (coatLength != null) {
      this._coatLength = coatLength;
    }
    if (goodWithStrangers != null) {
      this._goodWithStrangers = goodWithStrangers;
    }
    if (playfulness != null) {
      this._playfulness = playfulness;
    }
    if (protectiveness != null) {
      this._protectiveness = protectiveness;
    }
    if (trainability != null) {
      this._trainability = trainability;
    }
    if (energy != null) {
      this._energy = energy;
    }
    if (barking != null) {
      this._barking = barking;
    }
    if (minLifeExpectancy != null) {
      this._minLifeExpectancy = minLifeExpectancy;
    }
    if (maxLifeExpectancy != null) {
      this._maxLifeExpectancy = maxLifeExpectancy;
    }
    if (maxHeightMale != null) {
      this._maxHeightMale = maxHeightMale;
    }
    if (maxHeightFemale != null) {
      this._maxHeightFemale = maxHeightFemale;
    }
    if (maxWeightMale != null) {
      this._maxWeightMale = maxWeightMale;
    }
    if (maxWeightFemale != null) {
      this._maxWeightFemale = maxWeightFemale;
    }
    if (minHeightMale != null) {
      this._minHeightMale = minHeightMale;
    }
    if (minHeightFemale != null) {
      this._minHeightFemale = minHeightFemale;
    }
    if (minWeightMale != null) {
      this._minWeightMale = minWeightMale;
    }
    if (minWeightFemale != null) {
      this._minWeightFemale = minWeightFemale;
    }
  }

  int? get goodWithChildren => _goodWithChildren;
  set goodWithChildren(int? goodWithChildren) =>
      _goodWithChildren = goodWithChildren;
  int? get goodWithOtherDogs => _goodWithOtherDogs;
  set goodWithOtherDogs(int? goodWithOtherDogs) =>
      _goodWithOtherDogs = goodWithOtherDogs;
  int? get shedding => _shedding;
  set shedding(int? shedding) => _shedding = shedding;
  int? get grooming => _grooming;
  set grooming(int? grooming) => _grooming = grooming;
  int? get drooling => _drooling;
  set drooling(int? drooling) => _drooling = drooling;
  int? get coatLength => _coatLength;
  set coatLength(int? coatLength) => _coatLength = coatLength;
  int? get goodWithStrangers => _goodWithStrangers;
  set goodWithStrangers(int? goodWithStrangers) =>
      _goodWithStrangers = goodWithStrangers;
  int? get playfulness => _playfulness;
  set playfulness(int? playfulness) => _playfulness = playfulness;
  int? get protectiveness => _protectiveness;
  set protectiveness(int? protectiveness) => _protectiveness = protectiveness;
  int? get trainability => _trainability;
  set trainability(int? trainability) => _trainability = trainability;
  int? get energy => _energy;
  set energy(int? energy) => _energy = energy;
  int? get barking => _barking;
  set barking(int? barking) => _barking = barking;
  int? get minLifeExpectancy => _minLifeExpectancy;
  set minLifeExpectancy(int? minLifeExpectancy) =>
      _minLifeExpectancy = minLifeExpectancy;
  int? get maxLifeExpectancy => _maxLifeExpectancy;
  set maxLifeExpectancy(int? maxLifeExpectancy) =>
      _maxLifeExpectancy = maxLifeExpectancy;
  int? get maxHeightMale => _maxHeightMale;
  set maxHeightMale(int? maxHeightMale) => _maxHeightMale = maxHeightMale;
  int? get maxHeightFemale => _maxHeightFemale;
  set maxHeightFemale(int? maxHeightFemale) =>
      _maxHeightFemale = maxHeightFemale;
  int? get maxWeightMale => _maxWeightMale;
  set maxWeightMale(int? maxWeightMale) => _maxWeightMale = maxWeightMale;
  int? get maxWeightFemale => _maxWeightFemale;
  set maxWeightFemale(int? maxWeightFemale) =>
      _maxWeightFemale = maxWeightFemale;
  int? get minHeightMale => _minHeightMale;
  set minHeightMale(int? minHeightMale) => _minHeightMale = minHeightMale;
  int? get minHeightFemale => _minHeightFemale;
  set minHeightFemale(int? minHeightFemale) =>
      _minHeightFemale = minHeightFemale;
  int? get minWeightMale => _minWeightMale;
  set minWeightMale(int? minWeightMale) => _minWeightMale = minWeightMale;
  int? get minWeightFemale => _minWeightFemale;
  set minWeightFemale(int? minWeightFemale) =>
      _minWeightFemale = minWeightFemale;

  factory Behavior.fromJson(Map<String, int> json) =>Behavior(
    goodWithChildren : json['good_with_children'],
    goodWithOtherDogs : json['good_with_other_dogs'],
    shedding : json['shedding'],
    grooming : json['grooming'],
    drooling : json['drooling'],
    coatLength : json['coat_length'],
    goodWithStrangers : json['good_with_strangers'],
    playfulness : json['playfulness'],
    protectiveness : json['protectiveness'],
    trainability : json['trainability'],
    energy : json['energy'],
    barking : json['barking'],
    minLifeExpectancy : json['min_life_expectancy'],
    maxLifeExpectancy : json['max_life_expectancy'],
    maxHeightMale : json['max_height_male'],
    maxHeightFemale : json['max_height_female'],
    maxWeightMale : json['max_weight_male'],
    maxWeightFemale : json['max_weight_female'],
    minHeightMale : json['min_height_male'],
    minHeightFemale : json['min_height_female'],
    minWeightMale : json['min_weight_male'],
    minWeightFemale : json['min_weight_female']
  );
}

class UrlAlternative {
    UrlAlternative({
        required this.urls,
    });

    List<String> urls;

    factory UrlAlternative.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UrlAlternative(
        urls: List<String>.from(json["urls"].map((x) => x)),
    );

}
```

Please just focus on "behavior" field. The rest work correctly. Is there something I am missing in my factory method??

Comment: Not an actual question to your answer but you might wanna consider using freezed : https://pub.dev/packages/freezed 

It handles json for you by auto generating the required methods : https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#fromjsontojson

Comment: You can also use built_value package to make your json models in dart. it's clean and it generates all required methods for json serializations.
https://pub.dev/packages/built_value

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create my own classes if needed only. I use generators when my data is very complex, your case is not.

You need to firstly deal with raw data then you can use classes and methods because you know how it is structured and how it can be handled to get certain info about it, IMHO.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:_samples4/json/json_africa_wiki.dart';

typedef JMap = Map<String, dynamic>;

void main(List<String> args) {
  var list = (jsonDecode(rawJsonAfrica) as List).cast<JMap>();
  var data = list.first;
  var behaviour = (data['Behavior'] as List).first as JMap;
  print(behaviour.keys);
  print(behaviour.values);
}
```

Output:

```
(good_with_children, good_with_other_dogs, shedding, ..., min_weight_male, min_weight_female)
(3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 10, 14, 28, 28, 130, 100, 26, 26, 100, 70)
```